# Call function simultaneously with location.reload to display a proper message in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, reload

I have a onclick function which I call like this and then reload the page:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnAuthorize", function () {
        location.reload();
        $('#messageLoading').show();
    });
```

Is there any way to call a function which would display a pop-up while the page is reloading ?

The trick here is that page reload might take up to 30-50 seconds so I gotta display something to the end user.

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: you want pop-up during the page reloaded ?

Comment: Alert , or some other kind of pop-up message just to let user know something is happening

Comment: You are causing a page reload which throws away your running code. One option is to retain control and reload the page with an Ajax call, then replace the page with the returned HTML. As your code is still running that way you can do whatever you like during the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to literally reload the existing page (rather than switching to an ajax call, etc.), you can't do the "reloading" message in-page. What you *can* do is open a child window with a name:

```
var wnd = window.open("reloading.html", "reloading", "width=400,height=400,toolbar=no);
sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "Yes");
```

Note the session storage flag so we know whether we've done that. Then in the startup code for the page you're reloading, close that window:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("reloading")) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
    var wnd = window.open("", "reloading");
    if (wnd) {
        wnd.close();
    }
}
```

That looks strange, but calling `window.open` with a `""` URL and the same name as an open window your page origin has access to returns a reference to the **existing** window, which you can close.

The flag is important because otherwise, the `window.open` tries to open a *new* window, which will almost certainly trigger the popup blocker in your browser.

Here's a complete, working example (doesn't work correctly in a jsFiddle or Stack Snippet, those are sandboxed environments in various ways):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Reloading Window Example</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Reload">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (sessionStorage.getItem("reloading")) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
    var wnd = window.open("", "reloading", "height=400,width=400,toolbar=no");
    if (wnd) {
        wnd.close();
    }
}
$("input").on("click", function() {
    var wnd = window.open("", "reloading", "height=400,width=400,toolbar=no");
    wnd.document.write("<!doctype html><head><title>Reloading</title></head><body>Reloading...</body></html>");
    setTimeout(function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "Yes");
        location.reload();
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what's changing after page reload, but if you're showing "loading" message, you should be loading something in the meantime.

For that purpose use ajax (as you're using jquery):
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Load a result, a portion of a page or a whole new page and replace whatever needs replacing on success callback.