# javascript: pop up close when page refresh

Tags: javascript

Below is my javascript code.

pop up is getting opened but my page is refresh. Now I have to close the popup. I am trying to save `popupWindow` in localStorage. But when i am getting through  `localStorage.getItem("someVarName")`. I am not getting original dom, looks like its changed.
As my page is getting refresh, i have to save dom.

Please suggest how to do it.

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function openPopup(URL) {
    popupWindow = window.open(URL, 'popupWindow', 'height=300,width=450');
    localStorage.setItem("someVarName", popupWindow);
  }

  function closePopup() {
    var popupWindow = localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
    popupWindow.close();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: localstorage saves strings not objects and window references.

Comment: epascarello : So how to handle this case ?

Comment: I *just* answered a very, very similar question a day or two ago. *Edit:* Found it ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962589/call-function-simultaneously-with-location-reload-to-display-a-proper-message-in)), not sure whether this is a duplicate or not...

Answer (score 1):

Web storage stores **strings**. You can't store a window reference in it.

You *can*, though, store the name you used and reuse that with `window.open`:

```
function openPopup(URL) {
    window.open(URL, 'popupWindow', 'height=300,width=450');
    localStorage.setItem("someVarName", "popupWindow");
}

function closePopup() {
    var name = localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
    if (name) {
        var wnd = window.open("", name);
        wnd.close();
        localStorage.removeItem("someVarName");
    }
}
```

Calling `window.open` with the name of an existing window that your page has access to gives you a reference to that existing window, instead of opening a new one.

Note how I'm clearing the name from storage when the window isn't open, so we don't try to close it (which would, paradoxically, open it).

My [answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962679/157247) has a complete example.

Comment: Isnt this open new window ? This code : var wnd = window.open("", name);

Comment: @VJS: My sentence starting *"Calling `window.open` with the name of an existing window..."* should have ended with *"...to that existing window, **instead of opening a new one**"* (and now it does :-) ).